# Display video stream over http on xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, video-streaming

I'm streaming raspberry pi's pi camera over pi's local ip address with specific port. (eg: 192.168.1.111:8000/stream.mjpeg)

I can see the stream over xamarin.forms webview but I want to display it on Xamarin.Forms app with local media players for both iOs and android. Thus I can add control buttons for camera under the videoview. since it is live streaming I dont need forwards or backwards button functionallity.

I definitely lookup at least 5 pages per google search for all the keywords I have but there is nothing I find useful.

Any clues, starting points are appreciated too.

Comment: why not use a webview and add the control buttons beneath it?

Comment: @Jason Becouse on web view, you cannot use fullscreen option unless user changes orientation and some other functionalities like this.